# Get the last 14 days of records not included current date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble with the dates. I have here my code to count the records for the last 14 days from the current date but not including TODAY in the display.

Here's my SQL query

```
SELECT 
        a.TrackingCode,
        a.SegmentName,
        a.Brand,
        a.DateAdded,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a.DateAdded, GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_1",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a.DateAdded, GETDATE()) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_2",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a.DateAdded, GETDATE()) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_3",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a.DateAdded, GETDATE()) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_4",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a.DateAdded, GETDATE()) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_5",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a.DateAdded, GETDATE()) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_6",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a.DateAdded, GETDATE()) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_7",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a.DateAdded, GETDATE()) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_8",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a.DateAdded, GETDATE()) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_9",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a.DateAdded, GETDATE()) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_10",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a.DateAdded, GETDATE()) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_11",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a.DateAdded, GETDATE()) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_12",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a.DateAdded, GETDATE()) = 13 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_13",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, a.DateAdded, GETDATE()) = 14 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Day_14"
    FROM
        Journey_Injection_Logger_Base a
    WHERE
        a.DateAdded >= DATEADD(DD, -14, GETDATE())
        AND a.DateAdded <= GETDATE()    
    GROUP BY
        a.TrackingCode, a.SegmentName, a.Brand, a.DateAdded
```

The Day_1 is the yesterday's date. The problem is that when the next day comes it will add the new current date and my records for the Day_1 is not moving.

Sample output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaBsV.png)

From the above image of sample output. The record 2 should be in 4/14 TUE

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and `datediff()` or `dateadd()` is non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Hi I am writing this SQL query inside Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Comment: @CAR . . . If I had to speculate, this is a timezone issue.  The timezone you are in and the timezone the server is in are different, and you are not taking this into account.

Comment: Hi Gordon! Yup it is. Sorry for late response. This is also fixed adding timezone conversion. Thank you.